# "хоть стой(,) хоть падай"

Tags: пунктуация

Известно, что фразеологизмы запятыми не разделяются. А как быть с выражением "хоть стой(,) хоть падай"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна. Это явно однородные члены с противоположными значениями, и если бы вместо союза "хоть" стояло бы И или НИ, запятая бы не требовалась:

§ 146.
...
Примечание. Если повторяющимися союзами и, ни соединены два однородных члена с противоположными значениями, образующие одно цельное выражение, то запятая между ними не ставится, например:

ни то ни се, и так и этак, ни тот ни другой, ни да ни нет, и день и ночь, и стар и млад, и смел и горе, ни жив ни мертв, ни взад ни вперед, ни рыба ни мясо, ни дать ни взять. 
Запятая не ставится также между двумя однородными членами предложения, соединенными повторяющимся союзом и образующими тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов), например:

Были и лето и осень дождливы. 
Жуковский

Свод-57

В отношении же союза "хоть" таких рекомендаций нет. Более того есть прямые примеры:

~3.  
Употр. при сопоставлении предложений или отдельных членов предложения, по значению исключающих или заменяющих друг друга, для указания на допущение выбора между ними, согласия на выбор между ними. * Хоть честный человек, х. нет, Для нас равнёхонько (Грибоедов). * Спит - хоть голоден, хоть сыт, Хоть один, хоть в куче (Твардовский).

БТС (Кузнецов)

Answer (score 1):

"Ни днём ни ночью", "ни рыба ни мясо", "ни два ни полтора", "и стар и млад" и т.п. - цельные фразеологизированные сочетания с союзами ни..ни.., и.. и..; не ставим запятую, хотя и здесь соединяются однородные члены. "И муж и жена" - парное сочетание слов, когда "третьего не дано", запятую тоже не ставим. 
Но в случаях двукратного повторения любого другого союза, кроме И, запятая всегда ставится. В вашем случае это союз "хоть".

Comment: Не только И. См. мой ответ

Answer (score 0):

Фразеологизмы запятыми **НЕ ВЫДЕЛЯЮТСЯ**, если стоят в середине предложения, и **НЕ ОТДЕЛЯЮТСЯ**, если стоят в начале или в конце. Про разделение ни слова. *"Хоть стой, хоть падай"* - пишется так, ибо тут однородные члены, которые необходимо разделить.

Comment: Фразеологизмы не разделяются вообще.
На то они и фразеологизмы.

Валентин, ну вы хоть иногда следите за значением слов, вами употребляемых.